# What does it mean by $|A_5/K|$ and how to prove that $|A_5/K|\geq 5$?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, quotient-group

I saw the following exercise just now; it should have something to do with group actions:

> Let $K\leq A_5$. Show that $|A_5/K|> 4$.

I discovered I don't really understand what this means. First of all, $A_5$ is simple, so $K$ is not normal unless $K=A_5$ or $K=1$. So the quotient set $A_5/K$ is NOT a group. I guess that $|A_5/K|=|A_5: K|=|A_5|/|K|$, but this doesn't seem to be right. Also, when $A_5=K$,  $|A_5|/|K|=1$, so this is impossible.

What does this question mean? I am pretty shocked to be unable to understand it.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to make sense to me. Where did you come across it?

Comment: @Math1000 I saw it [here.](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/IA/Groups/2019-2020/Sheet4.pdf)

Comment: $K$ need not be a normal subgroup. This might be asking about the cardinality of the set of (left) cosets. That set isn't a group, but there is a natural $A_5$-action on it.

Comment: Yes...but what if $K=A_5$? Then it is not true...

Comment: Perhaps "proper subgroup" is missing by accident. I'm just guessing. There is no subgroup of index $2$. All you have to eliminate next is $3$.

Comment: @EthanBolker So I have to prove there is no order 20 subgroups? It is not easy.

Comment: I don't see how to do it in any obvious way. Maybe the group action hint in the problem will help. There are subgroups of order $10$ since the dihedral group $D_5$ lives in $A_5$.

Answer (score 1):

$G/H$ is standard notation for the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset#Notation for example.
In particular, $|G/H|=|G:H|$, as you surmised.

(When $H$ happens to be normal, then this notation is also used for the natural group on this set, as  you know.)

With the notation question out of the way, indeed you need $K<A_5$ for the question to be correct.